# How to handle static file missing in Play framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x, static-files

i used to declare my static ressources using the following code in my Play 1.2.5 templates :

```
<img src="@{'/public/images/team/myTeam.png'}"/>
```

My problem is when the specified file is missing, the view crashes... How can i avoid this problem ? I'd prefer displaying a view with a missing image rather than no view at all !

My context : i'm using Play 1.2.5 on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not a direct answer, maybe it will help you somehow.

Generally I would recommend removing public, static resources like images from the application to some CDN (I don't know Google's Engine, however fast search showed me that people does that) thanks to this you'll avoid displaying the error page. (nota bene displaying custom error page  for missing files makes no sense as you don't display the image separately but with `<img>` tag)

Additionally CDN gives you more profits, like caching files in closer distance from the client, while fetching files from CDN in another domain, the browser doesn't send whole redundant stuff like cookies, etc. Finally you can replace the resources without need of re-deploying the application.

Comment: Thank you biesor, indeed it would help. Do you have any advice about a free CDN ? We are a non-profitable organization and sadly we can not afford the services of Akamai & co :(

Comment: Nope, fortunately I had no such problem. First, cheapest option, just use some cheap host for storing files. I think that you'll find options for less than 50$ per year. Not a real CDN, however... of course there are other CDN providers like Amazon, Google, Microsoft etc. althought they aren't free, they offers ie. pricing per used GB's and free test periods.

Comment: BTW: search the web a little, there are some descriptions how to use Google App Engine as almost free CDN - they starting counting at some quite high level, so maybe you'll be able to use it totally for free if you'll prepare files well

Comment: Indeed i saw this possibility but google is not very clear about how its CDN works exactly. I'm gonna try to configure my app to use it, i'll see if ther is an improvement in performance :) But i don't think it will solve my play problem

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` is a HTML tag and has an [alt](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp) attribute that can be used to show instead of an image, when the image is not available. Besides, if you are working under debug mode, you probably see the error page, generated by play framework. Try switching to prod mode and inspect the results

Comment: Hello Alpay, the code presented in my question is just here to illustrate my problem, i already use the alt attribute in my app :) the fact is when a ressource is missing, the error page shows up, even in prod mode !